# Закрасить гистограмму разным цветом

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким способом можно раскрасить гистограмму используя параметр `colormap` чтобы отображалась вся палитра заданной темы, [например тема](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) - `turbo`?

Мой код:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", delimiter=";", encoding="utf-8").fillna("Null")
df.head()
vc = df["ID"].value_counts()
vc_id = (vc.loc[["79","787","20","125","119","89"]])
fig, ax_vc = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,8))
ax_vc.margins(y=0.45)
vc_id.plot(kind="bar", legend=False, colormap="turbo")
for i, perf in enumerate(vc_id):
    ax_vc.text(i, perf + 8, str(perf), color="black", ha="center", fontweight="bold", fontname="serif", fontsize=10)
plt.yscale("log")
plt.xticks(rotation=0)
plt.show()
```

Для раскраски гистограммы использую параметр `colormap="turbo"`, но гистограмма закрашивается только тем цветом, который идёт на 1ом месте [в шкале цвета](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html), т.е.:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал использовать подставку цветов через цикл:

```
colors = ["red" if i > 250 else "blue" for i in vc_id]
vc_id.plot(kind="bar", legend=False, color=colors)
```

Работает следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если добавить список цветов в переменную `colors = ["red", "blue", "green"]` то работает так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как всё таки использовать `тему цветовой палитры` в моём случае?

Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на ваш вопрос, как раскрасить столбцы в разные цвета при помощи `colormap` - **почти никак**.

Параметр `colormap` в `DataFrame.plot` определяет [каким цветом рисовать каждую отдельную колонку](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#colormaps). Так как у вас на чертеже только одна колонка, то все столбцы в случае colormap отрисовываются одним цветом.

Добавьте ещё пару колонок и посмотрите, что будет.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(\
                            {79 : 699, 787: 390, 20: 191, 125: 163, 119: 119, 89: 146},
                            orient='index',
                            columns=['Count']
)
df["c1"] = [100,200,300,400,500,600]
df["c2"] = [600,500,400,300,200, 100]

fig, ax_vc = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,8))
ax_vc.margins(y=0.45)
df.plot(kind="bar", legend=False, colormap="turbo", ax=ax_vc);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видите? У каждого набора свой цвет.

C параметром `color` дело обстоит хитрее. Когда у вас один набор данных, то цвета из `color` используются для раскрашивания отдельных столбцов, как у вас в примере. Если же наборов несколько, то цвета используются для выбора в какой цвет красить столбцы отдельных наборов.

```
df.plot(kind="bar", legend=False, color=["red", "green", "blue", "pink", "yellow", "black"])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Извлечь цвета из colormap**

Однако не всё потеряно. Можно извлечь цвета из цветовой карты и задать их для каждого столбца индивидуально.

Объект типа [`Colormap`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap) можно вызвать как функцию, передав параметр от 0 до 1. В ответ карта вернёт цвет в кодировке RGBA, соответствующий параметру.

```
turbo_cm = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('turbo')
colors = [turbo_cm(v) for v in np.linspace(0,1,len(df))]
df.Count.plot(kind="bar", legend=False, color=colors)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отлично. Спасибо!

Comment: Поспешил с заключением.

сделал:
`turbo_cm = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap("turbo")
colors = [turbo_cm(v) for v in np.linspace(0,1,len(df))]
vc_cwe.plot(kind="bar", legend=False, color=colors)`

не работает :(

Comment: @AlexRebell дайте ваш файл `test.csv`. Я же на своих данных делал. Может надо что-то ещё во внимание принять.

Comment: Извините, снова поспешил, нужно было указывать не `df` в `for v in np.linspace(0,1,len(df))]`, а в моём случае надо было `vc_id` в `for v in np.linspace(0,1,len(vc_id))]` - теперь всё работает. Спасибо.

Comment: @AlexRebell да, у меня `df` вместо ваших `vc_id`